# Why does SFML Shader cause segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sfml

Why does sf::Shader cause segmentation fault.I am going to show the code and i am telling to those that look the code that i use an engine and it works perfectly.So it doesn't cause the crash except with sf::Shader.And the code stops when i load the shader.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CoreEngine.h"
#include "maingame.h"

int main()
{
//CoreEngine e(new MainGame(new Vector2i(800, 600), "Mama"));
//e.start();
Window::createWindow(800, 600, "Mama");
Window::clearColor(124, 32, 125);

bool running = true;

while(running){
    if(Window::isWindowClosed())
        running = false;


sf::RectangleShape shape(sf::Vector2f(20, 20));
shape.setPosition(10, 10);
sf::Shader shader;
if(!shader.loadFromFile("fragment.fs", sf::Shader::Fragment))
    std::cout << "dfsfsdf";
    Window::clear();
    Window::getDrawer()->draw(shape, &shader);
    Window::render();
}
}
```

Here is a compiled version of the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
//CoreEngine e(new MainGame(new Vector2i(800, 600), "Mama"));
//e.start();
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Msadama");

sf::Shader shader;
if(!shader.loadFromFile("fragment.fs", sf::Shader::Fragment)){
    std::cerr << "Shader failed to load" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
sf::RectangleShape shape(sf::Vector2f(20, 20));
shape.setPosition(10, 10);
while(window.isOpen()){
   sf::Event event;

   while(window.pollEvent(event)){
    if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        window.close();
   }




    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
}
}
```

Comment: Are you supposed to load the shader every single frame?

Comment: hmm i didn't thought about that.Maybe that's the case.

Comment: Nope it doesn't work.

Comment: Your if statement should probably not have a `!`, that's checking if the load fails.

Comment: if i do that the if statement will trigger if it doesn't fail so it isn't that it has to be "!"  if loadFromFile returns false then it has to trigger not when it is true.So it isn't that.

Comment: So you *want* to draw a shader when it has failed to load?

Comment: No i am just doing what sfml has written on their website.
if(! (shader, texture, image).loadFromFile(filename))
#error here. Here is the page and look the code for loadFromFile http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-shader.php

Comment: From the documentation, `sf::Shader::loadFromFile` returns "True if loading succeeded, false if it failed". So if it fails, false is returned and your if-statement triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `sf::Shader::loadFromFile` is failing, which triggers your if statement because you are checking for the wrong condition. What you really want is:

```
sf::Shader shader;
if(!shader.loadFromFile("fragment.fs", sf::Shader::Fragment))
    std::cerr << "Shader failed to load" << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}

std::cout << "dfsfsdf";
Window::clear();
Window::getDrawer()->draw(shape, &shader);
Window::render();
```

Regardless, you shouldn't be loading your shader from a file every frame. Do it once, check the error, then enter the main loop. Something like this (untested):

```
int main()
{
    Window::createWindow(800, 600, "Mama");
    Window::clearColor(124, 32, 125);

    sf::Shader shader;
    if(!shader.loadFromFile("fragment.fs", sf::Shader::Fragment))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load shader" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    bool running = true;

    while(running){
        if(Window::isWindowClosed())
            running = false;

        sf::RectangleShape shape(sf::Vector2f(20, 20));
        shape.setPosition(10, 10);

        Window::clear();
        Window::getDrawer()->draw(shape, &shader);
        Window::render();
    }
}
```

Comment: that is the same thing.Except with the return status.When i want to print something after loadFromFile it just fails.It doesn;t event print.

Comment: i put the laod shader outside the while loop and it still doesn't work

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? The library presumably can't find that file.

Comment: That's thy the if statement is there.If it can't find the file it will trigger the if statement.

Comment: You need to think through the logic of your program. The if-statement in your question is triggered when the file can't be found, thus making the shader in a useless state. You then attempt to use this useless shader.

Comment: Ok to prove my point that loadFromFile cause segmentation fault.I removed the draw method where i use my shader and it still crashes even if i don;t use it

Comment: Have you used a debugger to find out where your program segfaults?

Comment: Yeah i used the debugger and it shows " Error while reading shared library symbols for libstdc++-6.dll" and it doesn't show the line of the segmentation fault.

Comment: Did you try getting a backtrace of the program when it segfaults? "bt" in gdb.

Comment: Yeah before the loadFromFile it prints on the console after the function it doesn't print anything.i have put a breakpoint on the function line and it showed me that it receives a signal segmentation fault

Comment: Edit your question with your current code in a way that can be compiled.

Comment: I can compile and run this with a [random shader](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/master/examples/shader/resources/pixelate.frag) I found. It must be an issue in your shader or `Window` class.

Comment: Well i use my compiled version of the code but it still didn't work with the random and my shader.Here is my shader:
#version 330

void main(){
gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5, 0.25, 0.1, 1);
}

Comment: So you are using the second version of the code, the shader is being loaded and you're still getting a segfault?

Comment: yes idk what it is.And i am using sfml 2.2 but i don't think that is the problem